# How to make everything lowercase automatically in Javascript as they type it in

Tags: javascript

How do I make all of the characters of a text box lowercase as the user types them into a text field in Javascript?

```
<input type="text" name="thishastobelowercase">
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hey @JordashTalon.  If any of the answers to the previous questions you asked work for you, then you should mark them answered.  This rewards those who work to help you and lets others know that the questions are answered.

Answer (score 30):

I would just make CSS do this for you instead of monkeying around with javascript:

```
<input type="text" name="tobelowercase" style="text-transform: lowercase;">
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="thishastobelowercase" style="text-transform: lowercase;">

Comment: It's important to note that this only affects the display, not the actual value. In other words in the UI you'll see all lowercase, but on the server side you'll see any uppercase characters that were used.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan +1. It is an **important note**.

Answer (score 14):

Two ways:

Using **CSS**:

```
.lower {
   text-transform: lowercase;
}

<input type="text" name="thishastobelowercase" class="lower">
```

Using **JS**:

```
<input type="text" name="thishastobelowercase" onkeypress="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();">
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Does it only have to *display* in lowercase, or does it have to *be* lowercase?  If you want to *display* lowercase, you can use CSS `text-transform: lowercase`.

You need to enforce this constraint server-side anyway, because the user can disable any JS code you put in to enforce that it remains lowercase.

My suggestion: use the CSS `text-transform` to make it always display in lowercase, and then do a `toLower` or your language's variant of it on the server-side before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mask for the type of validation that you want

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.maskSimpleName = function() {
        $(this).css('text-transform', 'lowercase').bind('blur change', function(){
            this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The advantage of using it is that the cursor will not go to the end of the input each character entered, as it would if using the a keyup or keupress solution.

```
$('#myinput').maskSimpleName();
```

This is a way to use it.

Obs: This mask sends the data in lowercase to the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 10 years later, but here's an easier way that I've found to do this - in case someone is still trying to do this.

Add the following event handler to the input tag in your HTML -

`oninput="event.target.value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();"`

Run the snippet below to test it out.

```js
const formElement = document.getElementById('lowercaseInput');

formElement.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  const formData = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.target).entries());
  console.log(formData);
});
```

```css
/* Copied from Bootstrap 4 styles */

.form-control {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: #495057;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: calc(1.6em + 0.75rem + 2px);
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #007bff;
  border: 1px solid #007bff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Note: Most of this code is just eye-candy.</h2>
<h3>The HTML for the "input" tag is the only important part here.</h3>

<form id="lowercaseInput">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" oninput="event.target.value = event.target.value.toLowerCase();" name="lowercaseText"/>
  <br>
  <button class="btn" type="submit" title="This will log the FormData values">Fake Form Submit</button>
</form>
<h4>Hit the "fake form submit" button to see what the server would get.</h4>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score -2):

Bootstrap Text transform:

```
<p class="text-lowercase">Lowercased text.</p>
<p class="text-uppercase">Uppercased text.</p>
<p class="text-capitalize">CapiTaliZed text.</p>
```