# Convert to lower the content of a textbox while typing

Tags: asp.net

I need to convert .ToLower() the content the user type on a textbox while he's typing... I found some exemples but it's all with the event `KeyPress` and in `asp.net` there's just the event `TextChange`, also, I found something with `Hegex` but somebody once told me that work with `hegex` is not a good practice... I'm a begginer so, i prefer to ask you guys, what's the better way to do this ?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999649/how-to-make-everything-lowercase-automatically-in-javascript-as-they-type-it-in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing the server and client side events. Note that the TextBox you declare in the .aspx will be rendered by default as a `input[type=text]`, so you can handle all the client side events (onkeypress, onkeyup, onkeydown, etc). But, what you want to accomplish can be done using only CSS. Put the following property in your textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Style="text-transform: lowercase;"></asp:TextBox>
```

This way, the text you enter will display as lowercase, but if want the text to really be **transformed** to lowercase, you must use Javascript:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();"
    Style="text-transform: lowercase;"></asp:TextBox>
```

By the way, using Regex is not a bad practice, it's just not necessary in this case. Regex is very useful for text searching, validation and parsing, making things a lot easier. The only trade-off is that some Regular Expression patterns can be very unclear and hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks man, but when I save that value on my DataBase, will save as lowercase ? Or it just shows as lowercase?

Comment: If you use the Javascript function `onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();"`, it'll be saved as lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to lower-case the text on the client-side as soon as the user enters text. You can handle that with the [`onkeypress` Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp):

```
<asp:TextBox Id="TextBox1" onkeypress="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();" runat="server" />
```

On the server side, which is not triggered on every keypress, but rather when you submit the page, you can use `String.ToLower`. For example if you handle the `TextBox` [`TextChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx):

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.ToLower();
}
```

Remember to add the event handler on the .aspx markup:

```
<asp:TextBox OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Id="TextBox1" />
```

Comment: I did like this: `<asp:TextBox ID="TxtLogin" runat="server" Width="170px" OnKeyPress="this.value.ToLowerCase();"></asp:TextBox> ` but still the same... ;\

Comment: @Ghaleon: Sorry, my `onkeypress` handler was not correct, edited my answer accordingly. `onkeypress="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();"`

Comment: Using the `onkeypress` event will result in the last letter remaining Uppercase, if it was an uppercase letter. http://jsfiddle.net/qGhg4/

Answer (score 0):

You can take the benefit of the css as suggested by @MarcusVinicius
Suppose you have a textbox like this

```
 <asp:TextBox id="text1" runat="server"/>
```

You can put cssClass on that as follows

```
<asp:TextBox id="text1" CssClass='text' runat="server"/>
```

and then create a css class

```
 .text
 {
   text-transform: lowercase;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks man, but, when I save that value on my DataBase, will save as lowercase ? Or it just shows as lowercase?

Comment: @Ghaleon It will be save in lowercase.